# How to fix name" Embedding is not defined" in Keras

Tags: keras, python-3.7

I am learning Keras from the book "Deep learning using Python".I was trying to implement the same as mentioned in the book on the implementation of the embedding layer. But I am getting error NameError: name 'Embedding' is not defined. I am using
Python 3.7
tensorflow: '1.13.1'
keras :'2.2.4'

```
from keras.models import Sequential                                    

from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense                                

model = Sequential()                                                   

model.add(Embedding(10000, 8 ,input_length= max_len))
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 model.add(Embedding(10000, 8 ,input_length= max_len))
>
> NameError: name 'Embedding' is not defined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to import the `Embedding` layer.

```
from keras.layers import Embedding
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add below line for importing the library to your python code.

```
from keras.layers import Embedding
```

https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/